# Soft Delete in Angular and Nest with Restore and Permanent Delete Functionality

Tags: angular, nest, soft-delete

Can you guy's help me out of this situation by giving idea how can I overcome this. I have two sections, one for ingredients and one for deleted items. Inside ingredient section if I clicks on delete button of a particular ingredient then it will be stored in deleted section. Inside deleted section for an ingredient it has two button one is restore- if I clicks here then it will restore the ingredient and move to ingredients section and another one is permanent delete button- if I clicks here then ingredients will be deleted permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas for how you can implement this functionality:

1. Use two arrays to store the ingredients and deleted items: You can
   use two separate arrays to store the ingredients and deleted items.
   When a user clicks the delete button for an ingredient, you can
   remove the ingredient from the ingredients array and add it to the
   deleted items array. When a user clicks the restore button for a
   deleted item, you can remove the item from the deleted items array
   and add it back to the ingredients array. When a user clicks the
   permanent delete button for a deleted item, you can remove the item
   from the deleted items array permanently.
2. Use a single array with a
   "deleted" flag: You can use a single array to store all the items,
   including both ingredients and deleted items. Each item in the array
   can have a "deleted" flag that is set to false for ingredients and
   true for deleted items. When a user clicks the delete button for an
   ingredient, you can set the "deleted" flag to true for that
   ingredient. When a user clicks the restore button for a deleted
   item, you can set the "deleted" flag to false for that item. When a
   user clicks the permanent delete button for a deleted item, you can
   remove the item from the array permanently.
3. Use a database to store
   the ingredients and deleted items: You can use a database to store
   the ingredients and deleted items. When a user clicks the delete
   button for an ingredient, you can update the database to mark that
   ingredient as deleted. When a user clicks the restore button for a
   deleted item, you can update the database to mark that item as not
   deleted. When a user clicks the permanent delete button for a
   deleted item, you can remove the item from the database permanently.

Comment: number 2 will be better for my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Most or all of your six answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.